# Anybody can help me analyze these code the backbone each function meanings?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Now , we can assume the app.Todos is a Collection. Then assume we had trigger the filterAll function .

```
filterOne : function (todo) {
  console.log(todo);
  todo.trigger('visible');
},


filterAll : function () {
  console.log(app.Todos);
  app.Todos.each(this.filterOne, this);
},
```

After i had read the underscore doc about each  , they say each_.each(list, iterator, [context]) , Iterates over a list of elements, yielding each in turn to an iterator function.

But the filterAll function use each to iterator a function this.filterOne ? So what's meaning ? This filterOne is not a list a elements , please help me .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From Underscore Documentation you see `_.each` as follows

```
_.each(list, iterator, [context])
```

Here list can also correspond to models.

So this can be written as

```
                       `app.Todos.each(function() { } , this);`

                                      **OR**

                       _.each(app.Todos.models, function() { } , this);
```

So this is equivalent to

```
app.Todos.each(function(todo) {
     console.log(todo);
     todo.trigger('visible');
}, this);
```

**OR**

```
_.each(app.Todos.models, function(todo) {
         console.log(todo);
         todo.trigger('visible');
 }, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

> This filterOne is not a list a elements , please help me .

The underscore functions are implemented as *methods* on the backbone instances. So your

```
app.Todos.each(this.filterOne, this);
```

is equivalent to

```
_.each(app.Todo.models, this.filterOne, this);
```

or [underscore's object wrapper](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-138):

```
_(app.Todo.models).each(this.filterOne, this);
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, that underscore functions are methods on backbone instances

Comment: Oops, I actually forgot the `.models` property to access the list